# Animating arcs waves

Tags: after-effects

With I could create an animation using arcs in After Effects as the example of the link below.

[Animation](https://goo.gl/images/RAaKJX)

I'm trying to animate only the region where the arcs are opening.

In After Effects I can not create arcs. My attempts were only with circles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achieve this effect using the built in Radio Waves effect.

https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/generate-effects.html

I think you can restrict the arc size.  If you can't, you could always mask the areas of the circle you don't want to see.

Comment: Very close to what I needed...